# Using Homebrew python in macOS app?

Tags: python, homebrew

I have recently switched to the homebrew version of Python and, after some initial hickups (had to change to `#!/usr/bin/env python` in some scripts that were explicitly asking for the system Python), everything seemed to work fine on the command line.

However, we have a `Foo.app` directory that acts as a glorified wrapper around a Python script inside so we can associate it with some file type. When the app is run (e.g. by clicking on an associated file), the script is called not with my environment but with some default environment (or at least the brew is not on PATH), and thus system Python is used.

My questions are:

- Can I make that app run with the user's environment to use brew Python?
- Or if it already is, what did I do wrong to have brew Python on the command line but not when running this app?